# Array parameter in a request html don't work

Tags: c#, html, json

In Chrome Developer Tools, XHR option, I have this informations:

Request URL:https://pmv.geocontrol.com.br/pontovitoria/svc/json/db/listarPontosDeParada

Request Payload:
{listaIds: [216, 147, 607, 601, 79]}

I'm trying to transform it in a unique html, like

https://pmv.geocontrol.com.br/pontovitoria/svc/json/db/listarPontosDeParada?listaIds[0]=216&listaIds[1]=147&listaIds[2]=607&listaIds[3]=601&listaIds[4]=79

but I receive this error

errorClass: "javax.servlet.ServletException",
message: "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")" Position: 273"

I'm developing a app in C# and I try this post request:

```
public async void GetList()
{
        int[] list = new int[] { 216, 147, 607, 601, 79 };

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Other");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.IfModifiedSince = DateTime.Now;

        Dictionary<string, string> bodyProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        int i = 0;
        foreach (var pto in list)
        {
            bodyProperties.Add("listaIds[" + i.ToString() + "]", pto.ToString());
            i++;
        }

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(bodyProperties);
        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://pmv.geocontrol.com.br/pontovitoria/svc/json/db/listarPontosDeParada", content);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

This isn't work. How can I solve it?

Comment: The unique URL example you give doesn't work either?

Comment: Looks like malformed JSON to me. You're missing a colon between the array name and the array.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comments. I find the solution.

The right url is:

https://pmv.geocontrol.com.br/pontovitoria/svc/json/db/listarPontosDeParada?listaIds[]=216,147,607,601,79